# WebAPI W OData & EF : navigation property error

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

Good Morning,

I've created a WebApi with EF on DB SQLServer. I've also utilized OData vers 4.0.
I need to expand the model in order to create relationships not present in database.

- I've an entity CLOCK and another INTERFACE (1 INTERFACE - N CLOCKS)
- I've expanded the model in the following way:

  ```
  public partial class Clock
  {
      /*
      OData needs this field, I don't want to modify EF mapping autogenerated files
      */
      [Key]
      public int ID
      {
          get { return this.ClockID; }
          set { this.ClockID = value; }
      }
      public Interface
      {
          get
          {
              using (EF.DBClocksContainer db = new EF.DBClocksContainer())
              {
                  return db.tbl_Interface.Where(x => x.ID == this.InterfaceID).SingleOrDefault();
              }
          }
          set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
      }
  ```

I've created a new controller using OData 4 scaffolding: then I have a controller with OData 4 on the Clock entity of the EF's model and the CRUD methods.

The GET method, which return an IQueryable, is simple. Simply apply the odata query:

```
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<Clock> GetClocks(ODataQueryOptions<Clock> queryOptions)
        {
            return db.tbl_Clock;
        }
```

In global.asax file, in addition WebApi registration where setting routing rule etc, I added other custom register for OData's rules:

```
Global.asax:

[…]
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
            {
                ODataConfig.Register(config); //this has to be before WebApi
                WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            });

[…]


ODataConfig:

        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); //This has to be called before the following OData mapping, so also before WebApi mapping

            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

            builder.EntitySet<Clock>("Clocks");

            config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
        }
```

Now the error...

With Postman, doing a simple GET, everything works:

```
http://localhost:51432/odata/Clocks
```

I receive the list of clocks with the first-level properties => not the 'Interface' filed. For the ‘navigation properties’ with odata, we must use $expand comand:

```
http://localhost:51432/odata/Clocks?$expand=Interface
```

Now I receive the following error:

```
[…]
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; odata.metadata=minimal'.",
[…]
The specified type member 'Interface' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.",
[…]
```

However, the strangest thing is the following: if I do a single element GET with the $expand method all correctly works:

```
http://localhost:51432/odata/Clocks(2)?$expand=Interface
```

Have you some ideas?

Thanks. Nicola.

I solved by adding associations in the EF model. Nicola.

Comment: I can't repro with almost the same of your code, can you create issue on https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues and provide a repro detail, like the auto generated model class, I'll look into for you.